# Rename jpeg files sequentially in multiple subfolders

Tags: bash, macos, unix, find

How can I rename a lot of jpegs files that are in a lot of subfolders sequentially? 
At the moment a lot of them have the same file name (eg. frame1.jpeg).
I only want to have a 6 digit numeric suffix on all jpg files that have  "frame" in the file name but in a sequence so that later on I can move them in one folder without the danger that they are being overwritten.

Theres probably a way to do it with **find** but I don't know how…

this is my folder structure:

```
├── mainfolder
|    ├── subfolder1
|    |   ├── frame1.jpg
|    |   └── frame2.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder2
|    |   ├── frame1.jpg
|    |   └── frame2.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder3
|    |   ├── frame.jpg
|    |   └── frame2.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
…
```

This is how I imagine the files to be named in the end:

```
├── mainfolder
|    ├── subfolder1
|    |   ├── frame0000001.jpg
|    |   └── frame0000002.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder2
|    |   ├── frame0000003.jpg
|    |   └── frame0000004.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
|    |
|    ├── subfolder3
|    |   ├── frame0000005.jpg
|    |   └── frame0000006.jpg
|    |   └── unimportant.jpg
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all new, unfamiliar commands, please try this on a **copy** of your files, after making a backup of your machine. Also, do not try this in your HOME directory as it recurses down into sub-directories, so try it in a directory below which you have nothing important!

I think I understand! If you use **homebrew**, you can use:

```
brew install rename
```

to install the Perl `rename` command.

Then you can run this:

```
find . -name "frame*.jpg" -print0 | rename --dry-run --stdin -0 -N "000001" '$_="frame" . $N . ".jpg"'
```

which says... *"Find all the JPEG files in the current directory and below, that start with `frame...` and pass their names to `rename` with null termination. The `rename` utility then reads the null-terminated names and starts a counter `$N` with 6 digits total width and sets the filename to the word `frame` followed by the sequential number, incrementing by 1 for each file and appending the `.jpg` suffix"*.

If the output looks good, run again without the `--dry-run`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and your explanation! I had to add a "." in front of the "jpg" in the end of the code as files were called frame1jpg instead of frame1.jpg but besides that it worked perfectly!

Comment: Well done! Thanks for letting me know the mini-mistake. I have updated my answer to correct that, Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code will print a list of `mv` command that should to what you want:

```
#! /bin/bash

seqnum=1
find mainfolder -type f -name 'frame*.jpg' -print0 \
    |   while IFS= read -r -d '' jpg_path ; do
            dir=${jpg_path%/*}
            printf -v new_jpg_path '%s/frame%06d.jpg' "$dir" $((seqnum++))
            echo mv -i -- "$jpg_path" "$new_jpg_path"
        done
```

One you are happy that it will do the right thing, remove the `echo` before the `mv ...` and run it to actually perform the renames.  The `-i` option to `mv` is to protect against overwriting files that might already exist.